# How to deploy windows app store project (Visual Studio Ultimate 2012)

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro

I have a windows app store project and I wish to deploy it so that it have its set up file(ClickOnce). I searched online and tried a few methods like using InstallShield but it doesn't work. 
I hope to hear from any help. Thank you very much.

Comment: Did you try creating the app package ? Do you want it to be Deployed in the store or in your machine or a surface tablet ? If you answer these Ill proceed with an Answer.

Comment: Hi Anobik, I will wish to deploy it to my machine and other machines(for setting up) as well. I had tried packaging it, but when I run it using powershell on another machine, it fails. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First installing package using Power Shell you would need to

- If you have a Machine for test try installing in that.
- If the app is already installed please un-install it and then re install with new package.
- Make sure all the contents of the app package is in the other machine(total 1 folder 1 file and inside the folder app. inside the folder two more folders and 3 files including the power shell ).

After all these go through this link and check 
[Install from powershell](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/uk_faculty_connection/archive/2012/04/03/installing-enterprise-metro-apps-without-using-microsoft-store.aspx)

Let me know if it worked else Ill go on searching for more.

Comment: Hi Anobik, the installation of the project failed after running with powershell on another machine. But all the files are there and it's installed successfully on my machine.